# Specified config does not exist in ZooKeeper: solr

Tags: ubuntu, solr, apache-zookeeper

- I have installed solrcloud with zookeeper 3 nodes.
- I have 5 collections in solr each having different config_name
- I have stopped solr & zookeeper instances & start it again but when I started the instances it gives below error - 
  "collection1_shard1_replica2: org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ZooKeeperException:org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ZooKeeperException: Specified config does not exist in ZooKeeper: general_conf"
- Before stopping solr & zookeeper instances I have removed log files which are available under folder "/zkData/zk1/" , "/zkData/zk2", "/zkData/zk3" these are zookeeper folder containing logs

Comment: How do you start the nodes on your SolrCloud? do you do it like the reference pages: `./bin/solr start -cloud -s example/cloud/node1/solr -p 8983`